# I am gettin error when I call Web Service (SSL)

Tags: java, web-services, ssl

When I invoke my Webservice I am getting error like below, please explain it how I can solve this problem.

Error is:

> fault Description : nulldetail : faultCode:Server.Processing
>   faultString:'javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException : General SSLEngine
>   problem' faultDetail:'null'

I am using tomcat server in my local.

I'm using 1.6 Java Runtime Environment and I added Webservice SSL into:

`jdk1.6>jre>lib>security>cacerts` .

but nothing changed. Do I need configure my tomcat server

Comment: Very bad style. Never ever modify something within the jre directory unless there is no other way to get the same result! Check StackOverflow for other ways how to add your custom trust certificate.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem . You dont need to any configuration your server . Or JRE .
Just put it this code

```
       public String retrieveMngTracking(ArrayList paramList) throws Exception {

             //ı added for SSL
    HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession session) {
            System.out.println("Warning: URL Host: " + urlHostName
                    + " vs. " + session.getPeerHost());
            return true;
        }
    };



    ParamMap paramMap = FlexUtil.getParamMap(paramList);

    URL url = new URL(paramMap.getString("url"));

    //Call this function for SSL
    trustAllHttpsCertificates();
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setReadTimeout(20000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(os);

    wr.write("pMusteriNo=" + paramMap.getString("pMusteriNo"));
    wr.write("&pSifre=" + paramMap.getString("pSifre"));
    wr.write("&pSiparisNo=" + paramMap.getString("pSiparisNo"));
    wr.write("&pKriter=" + paramMap.getString("pKriter"));

    wr.flush();

    wr.close();
    os.close();

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            conn.getInputStream()));

    String response = "";
    for (;;) {
        String line = br.readLine();
        if (line == null)
            break;
        response += line + "\n";
    }
    br.close();

    conn.disconnect();

    return response;
}
     public static class miTM implements javax.net.ssl.TrustManager,
        javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager {
    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isServerTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isClientTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs) {
        return true;
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
            throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
        return;
    }

    public void checkClientTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
            throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
        return;
    }
}

private static void trustAllHttpsCertificates() throws Exception {

    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains:

    javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[] trustAllCerts =

    new javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[1];

    javax.net.ssl.TrustManager tm = new miTM();

    trustAllCerts[0] = tm;

    javax.net.ssl.SSLContext sc =

    javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, null);

    javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(

    sc.getSocketFactory());

}
```

Ok everything perfect in my local my local server is tomcat . But When ı want to deploy Weblogic server same error giving . Please explain it why everything work my local but now weblogic server problem.